# Getting start time from a datetime range in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the start date and start times into 2 separate columns in a select query from a column that has a range of date time.

| Date |
| --- |
| 1/1/22 12:00 pm - 1/1/22 12:59 pm |
| 1/1/22 1:00 pm - 1/1/22 1:59 pm |
| 12/31/21 7:00 am - 12/31/21 7:59 am |
| 12/31/21 11:00 am - 12/31/21 11:59 am |

So far I am able to do the start date using this:

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(DATE,RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT([Date], CHARINDEX(' ',[Date]) + 0))))))
```

I am encountering errors with my start time, the code I am at right now is this:

```
RTRIM(LTRIM(FORMAT(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(RIGHT(RIGHT(LEFT([Date], CHARINDEX('-', [Date]) - 1), LEN(LEFT([Date], CHARINDEX('-', [Date]) - 1)) - CHARINDEX('/21 ',LEFT([Date], CHARINDEX('-', [Date]) - 1))),LEN(RIGHT(LEFT([Date], CHARINDEX('-', [Date]) - 1), LEN(LEFT([Date], CHARINDEX('-', [Date]) - 1)) - CHARINDEX('/21 ',LEFT([Date], CHARINDEX('-', [Date]) - 1)))) - 1))),'am','AM'),'pm','PM') AS datetime),'hh:mm tt')))
```

I wanted the format to be hh:mm am/pm. I think what is causing the error is the counts/index of the characters but I am not sure how to resolve this.

This is my desired result:

| Date | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/22 | 12:00 pm |
| 1/1/22 | 1:00 pm |
| 12/31/21 | 7:00 am |
| 12/31/21 | 11:00 am |

Comment: Must you do this in SQL Server?  This would be fairly easy to handle using regular expressions.  But core SQL Server does not support regex.

Comment: Yes I would need this done in SQL Server

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 Management Studio 13.0.16106.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the base strings functions we can try:

```sql
SELECT
    Date,
    LEFT(Date, CHARINDEX(' ', Date) - 1) AS Date,
    SUBSTRING(Date,
              CHARINDEX(' ', Date) + 1,
              CHARINDEX(' ', Date, CHARINDEX('-', Date) + 1) -
                  CHARINDEX(' ', Date) - 3) AS Time
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo